# Versions in Flutter-Project incompatible

Tags: flutter, versioning, pubspec.yaml

I have programmed a App with flutter but since the update of Android Studio to version electric eel I face a missmatch in versions of packages.

This is a part of my pubspec.yaml:

```
...
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
url_launcher: ^6.0.13
package_info_plus: ^2.0.0
page_transition: ^2.0.4
sqflite: ^2.1.0+1
path_provider: ^2.0.11
material_design_icons_flutter: ^6.0.7096
permission_handler: ^10.0.0
badges: ^2.0.2
stack: ^0.2.1
flutter_slidable: ^2.0.0
date_time_picker: ^2.1.0
page_indicator: ^0.4.1
table_calendar: ^3.0.8
provider: ^6.0.2
syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^21.1.39
flutter_cached_pdfview: ^0.4.1
...
```

When I try to build the app anew or by executing flutter pub get, I receive this:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Because no versions of date_time_picker match \>2.1.0 \<3.0.0 and date_time_picker 2.1.0 depends on intl ^0.17.0, date_time_picker ^2.1.0 requires intl ^0.17.0.
And because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.18.0, date_time_picker ^2.1.0 is incompatible with flutter_localizations from sdk.
So, because sysdiapulsgew depends on both flutter_localizations from sdk and date_time_picker ^2.1.0, version solving failed.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to change versionnumbers and I read the manuals on pub.dev for each package...

Hope someone has help...

Comment: try to use updated package version by visiting pub.dev

Comment: this is what I've done first but with no effect :(

Comment: try to remove all version and use any like `packageName:any`

Comment: Glad to help , after setting `any` and pub get, you can check `pubspec.lock` for the compatible version